# Using methods and variables outside of class

Tags: flutter

[image]

on my flutter app, I'm using some variables and functions like this, outside of class, without dependency injection so I can access them from everywhere.

the question is: Is this bad for performance or has any bad effect on my app?

Comment: It's ok, you can create a `constants.dart` file and add all your variable there starting with `k` letter, like Flutter does `kToolbarHeight` , `kBottomNavigationBarHeight` etc..

Comment: If they are constants and not variables, prefix them with `const` or `final` during declaration and initialization. And I agree, collect all of them into the file `constants.dart` which you can import into other files.

Answer (score 0):

As I know this is not bad for performance because a lot of functions and variables we use in flutter like Colors class is outside the ui state class.
And I all Get.* is outside the ui state class>

Answer (score 0):

It is not a good practice as far as Object Oriented Programming is concerned!

Encapulating methods, and fields is necessary to make our code work as it is intended, otherwise, anyone can change anything which could lead to potential problems down the lane.

As Andrea Bizzotto says "Making our code easy to use as it is intended and tougher to use otherwise"